# How to wait for API response to go from Pending to complete?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

This question is asked often, answered seldomly, and as far as I can find, not at all in this context, although I would love to be proven wrong, even at the loss of a few reputation points.  ;-)

I have made an API call in C#, and the `HttpResponseMessage` is immediately "Pending".

```
JObject thing = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

thing["status"] // "Pending"
```

I thought maybe wrapping it in a loop and retrying it over and over, but the "Pending" response never changes:

```
while (true) {

    JObject thing = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

    Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
}

thing["status"] // remains "Pending"
```

I even tried recalling the end point inside this loop:

```
while (true) {

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

    JObject thing = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

    Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
}
```

But that complains that I cannot make the same request more than once.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: What is complaining about *making the same request more than once*? Did you check whether the API has some retry / update policy that your requests are supposed to respect? What is *pending*? -- Why are you awaiting `SendAsync()` and `ReadAsStringAsync()` but not `Task.Delay()`?  -- Could be useful, though probably overshooting here: [Implement HTTP call retries with exponential backoff with IHttpClientFactory and Polly policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-http-call-retries-exponential-backoff-polly)

Comment: @Jimi, "await client.SendAsync(request)", if inside the loop, errors, claiming that I cannot submit the request more than once.  And, yes, thank you that link was helpful.

Comment: What .NET version are you targeting? I don't remember `SendAsync()` complaining about resending the same message, but I don't know how your `HttpClient` and its `HttpClientHandler` / `SocketsHttpHandler` (you should use the latter when building a resilient request) - or the `HttpRequestMessage` for that matter - are configured. You could simply recreate the message in the loop -- Do yourself a favor, replace this: `Task.Delay(1000).Wait();` with the obvious `await Task.Delay(1000);`

Comment: To be pedantic: always specify the .NET version you're targeting and what kind of application framework you're using. Both quite relevant; lots of nuances are platform specific

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using a variation of long polling to check the status from your response. However, infinite loops have a tendency to get stuck if there is no exit condition.

A publisher/subscriber model will be better than long polling if you have control over the API and the code interacting with the API. I would recommend creating a new API (listener) that can receive an event when your other process completes.

```
public async Task WorkCompleted(WorkCompletedEventData data) {
  // do something with the event data
}
```